# How can I run NiFi processes on multiple AWS VMs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-nifi

I want to use NiFi to create, manage, and run process threads on multiple AWS VMs. I understand that I can use Remote Process Groups to do that. However, the use case for that approach seems to require that I create the VMs I need beforehand and then configure NiFi to run process threads on them. However, I want to spin up one or more VMs when the user starts a process, as one of the main purposes of my project is to provide configurable and adaptable load-balancing across multiple VMs. All the NiFi examples I've seen that use AWS run on pre-configured VMs, and I'm not sure how to implement my requirements with NiFi.

I first looked at modifying NiFi source code to enable me to specify at run-time the host URL on which to run a process. After looking through the NiFi implementation, this seems to not be a feasible approach. The other idea I have is to create a NiFi Process whose job is to spin up AWS VMs based on user input, and then somehow connect the output of this Process (with the URL of the VM that was started) to NiFi threads whose processes are running on separate VM instances. I'm not sure if that approach is feasible either.

Can anyone comment on the viability of either of the above approaches, or recommend an alternative approach for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Downvoting without comment is apparently how some people choose to welcome you to StackOverflow.

Comment: why not to start from dockerizing nifi cluster and after that think how to run those dockers on any cloud?